# cc.BuilderReader is not defined

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have downloaded Cocos2d-html5-v2.1.0 and added below code to sample(main.js):

```
var scene = cc.BuilderReader.loadAsScene("ccb/Menu.ccbi");?         
cc.Director.getInstance().replaceScene(scene);
```

but I get the following error:

> TypeError: cc.BuilderReader is undefined

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
loadExtension:true,
```

in the file you use to define cocos behaviours like showFPS and box2d etc, (you might have called it cocos2d.js)